# Consequences of Keeping Unconfigured Link Up Permanently

Tags: linux, networking

Unconfigured links can remain in the “UP” state (`IFF_RUNNING`
bit set) independent of whether an IP address is configured or
not:

```
ip addr show dev eth8
8: eth8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 42:01:ff:ff:ff:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

One of the advantages of this is that one can perform trivial
connectivity tests with [un-]plugging the ethernet cable.

Are there any practical downsides to keeping it in this state
permanently? How much of an overhead does the “UP” state have
kernel-side?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the only practical downside it has (unless you have a *lot* of interfaces, like thousands—though of course even then downing one interface wouldn't matter) is that Ethernet ports consume more power when up, and even more with a link up. So on a laptop, you'd be shortening battery life slightly.

Also, I suppose anything sending/receiving raw Ethernet frames could use it. Also if you had IPv6 enabled, with the default settings it'd get a v6 link-local address.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I’m envisioning more of a router / server kind of scenario though, where usually one has more nics at one’s disposal than necessary at any given time.